# Webtracker using nodejs

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to create a webtracker to track what pages my users are seeing and how much time they are spending at each page, at the end they will make a registration and i will associate their navigation with the created user.

I want to use node because i can see when the user connect to the url and disconnect to calculate the time, i have tried that with pure javascript but i can see when the user leaves the page only on Chrome.

I have already managed to create some of what i need using the `socket.io` lib but i can't find a way to use it without creating an html page. What i need is to create something like google analytics where i will only incorporate the script. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to figure it out so i will post it to help others with the same problem:

**Server**

```
let socket = require('socket.io');
let http = require('http');
let serveStatic = require('serve-static');
let finalhandler = require('finalhandler');

var port = process.env.PORT || 1337;
let serve = serveStatic(__dirname, { 'index': ['client.js'] });

let server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    serve(req, res, finalhandler(req, res));
});

let io = socket(server);

server.listen(port);

io.on('connection', client => {
    console.log('new user connected!', client.id);

    client.on('hello', data => {
        console.log('data: ', data);
    });

    client.on('disconnect', () => {
        console.log('user disconnected', client.id);
    });
});
```

**Client**

```
(function (plugin) {
    plugin.socket = null;

    function loadDependencies() {
        head.js(
            { socket: 'https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js' }
        );

        head.ready('socket', function() {
            plugin.socket = io('http://localhost:1337');

            setSocketHandlers();
        });
    }

    function setSocketHandlers() {
        plugin.socket.on('my-event', function(data){
            console.log('called my event');
        });
    }

    plugin.init = () => {
        loadDependencies();
    }
}(this.WebTracker = this.WebTracker || {}));

WebTracker.init();
```